# Is it possible to launch webdriver from Javascript?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Meaning to create a JSP page and when clicking a button it will launch a webdriver ?
I thought to do it using a javascript ....
Is it possible ? and if so can some one tell me how to do it ....
Thanks :)

Comment: I read this http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs And i got a little lost there. can you please give me directions how to get started . im not sure what is this "node" and what should i import to the project, im a little new at this.... im sure this post can help every one thanks :)

Comment: I will clarify what i meant:
1. What is this "node" they talking about ?
2. I couldnt if there is a new jar to import 
3. How to activate this and what is this command mean $ ./go webdriverjs
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. Currently the webdriver development team just launched webdriverJS.For details you could see the following url:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

Comment: Binken Zou, your comment is stupid. Arik already visited that site, but unfortunately he could not understand some terms. He needs some specific answer for specific question mentioned above by Arik